# How to add a new client to IdentityServer4 in the database?

Tags: identityserver4

During the first tests I always used the `AddInMemoryClients` configuration of IdentityServer4 as described in [their documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html).

However I'm in the process of deploying it to our test environment and want to get rid off the configuration file so I've setup the [Entity Framework integration](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html).

Now all client ID's, client secrets, scopes, ... are persisted in the database in an encrypted way.
However, it's more difficult to add a new client.

What's the appropriate way to configure this?

Using Entity Framework migrations?

I know there's [a UI](https://www.identityserver.com/documentation/admin-ui/) available on top of IdentityServer4 but is that the only "easy" way?

Comment: For now I have created an MVC controller in my IdentityServer solution and created a form which allows me to add new clients.

The MVC controller itself is then protected with Windows Authentication and only allows specific AD groups.

Comment: can you provide some insert samples, incuding relations between clients and scopes and api resources?

Comment: @ibubi This was a solution I created with a client I left a year ago and I don't have the source anymore. Maybe these scripts can get you started?

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/tree/dev/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations

Answer (score 0):

```
var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>()
context.Database.Migrate()
use this too create context 

Code for client json for seed

new Client
{
    ClientId = "js",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
    RequirePkce = false,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RedirectUris = JsConfig.RedirectUris.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray(),
    //FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44300/signout-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = JsConfig.PostLogoutRedirectUris.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray(),
    AllowedCorsOrigins = JsConfig.AllowedCorsOrigins.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray(),
    AllowPlainTextPkce = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("secret".Sha512()) },
    //AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "scope2" },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
     {
        //Omitted for brevity        
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
     },
    ClientName = "eXate Portal",
    DeviceCodeLifetime = 0,

}

For Add
context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity())
```