# Adding values in Client Table identitysever

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a client with following details

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "clientid",
    AllowedGrantTypes = allowedGrantTypes,
    ClientSecrets =new List<Secret> { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
    AllowedScopes = { IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess},
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 60,
    RefreshTokenExpiration =  TokenExpiration.Sliding,
    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 60*43200,
    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 0
},
```

I need to configure the app so that the details are fetched from db

So how to configure the databases for client secrets

Now I defined like this, but the app is resulting

[image: Client secret]

> IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator:Error: Client secret validation failed for client:

I need to encode string to sha256 format.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730043/how-to-add-a-new-client-to-identityserver4-in-the-database?rq=1) but no suitable solution found.

What should be the type that is to be given in the `type` field in the table for storing sha256 encryption

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You already calculate the hash in your code example?

Comment: @Tseng i need it to move from InMemory to db

Comment: Still not clear. You add db support to IdSrv by calling `AddOperationalStore`/`AddConfigurationStore` instead of `AddInMemoryXxx` method inside Startup.cs. Nothing else changes to have a persistent store

Comment: IdSrv uses Entity Framework in the background, you just add your models as you would with any other EF Core `configDbContext.Clients.Add(new Client { ... })` either via seeding or a UI you make which allows you adding new clients, the code base is same though

Comment: @Tseng So you are saying that the clients cannot be added manually/directly to the table and then execute the app?

Comment: It can be done, but you should never add things manually to a database. This effectively bypasses all checks, validations and rules enforced the application is doing. An application should own the database and be the only one who ever writes to it. A 2 seconds google search https://www.google.com/search?q=calculate%20sha256%20hash gives you tons of online sha256 calculators or commandline tools which calculate it for you for a given value

Comment: @Tseng So what values should be provided for the secret types field in the db. This database is generated from the scripts mentioned in the identityserver repo

Comment: As a better practice you suggest creating client,resource models and injecting those at startup? @Tseng

Comment: You dont need to inject anything, once they are seeded for the first time, they remain in the database. But since its an Auth Provider its perfectly fine that **NO CLIENT** is configured when the app is shipped/installed for the first time and you add clients via an administrative page whenever you need a client. IdSrv4 doesnt come with a free UI,so you either have to write the UI yourself of buy the UI addon product from the IdSrv4 creators.All you need is to seed an admin user (with given username and password,which you could store in the appsettings or via app parameters on the first start)

Comment: @Tseng as u said above i tried with encoding the client secret with sha256 encryption in the database, but the app fails with the same error. what and how should the type should be specified for the secret keys stored in the database in identity server